# Shortest C++ code to cause an access violation

Tags: c++, obfuscation

Can we go shorter (character-wise) or more elegant than:

```
*(int*)0=0;
```

The goal is to raise an access violation. Platform independent solutions are preferred.

Comment: If you hide a single character typedef elsewhere (possibly a template parameter), you can save 2 characters from your way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not including includes into your character count

For Linux:

```
raise(11); //SIGSEGV
```

For Windows:

```
raise(SIGSEGV); // I don't know the SIGSEGV value for sure so more characters required
```

Comment: For Windows, it isn't as short and sweet: RaiseException(STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE,0,NULL);  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You gotta love the compat team :)

Comment: Sorry, that's longer though than the initial suggested and needs an ifdef for differentiation.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek, raise(11) is 9 characters long. The suggested option is 10 characters long. It is non portable but it is smaller. For Windows, all you have to do is to printf("%d",SIGSEGV) and then replace the value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way of causing a segmentation violation or another similar error.

Compilers can and do assume that undefined behavior never occurs. If they detect UB in a certain branch of code, they have every right to optimize the entire branch out of existence.

```
if (x == 5) 
{
  std::cout << "Gonna crash";
  *(int*)0 = 42;
}
```

A compiler can translate this block of code to a no-op.

`raise(SIGSEGV)` may or may not cause an actual violation, but it is the only portable way of cause a program to behave *as if* a violation has occurred.

Comment: Which compiler would do this? Any of GCC, MSVC, XCode or Clang?

Comment: I don't know of a current compiler that does exactly this, but some do very similar things. Look [here](http://ideone.com/gilyHa). The program should have crashed on the third iteration, right? And why doesn't the loop end?

Comment: clang will warn you that "indirection of non-volatile null pointer will be deleted, not trap", but AFAICT it does not actually delete the indirection. See [this](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23831)

Comment: Sometimes it does work... http://ideone.com/P3AeRi - I agree that the compiler might interfere with the access violation, but in the case of ideone.com I guess that they use a exception handler which might just continue...

Comment: Nope, the problem here is that `i*1000000000` overflows when `i >= 3`, so the compiler assumes `i` is never `>=3`, and deletes all the corresponding checks and branches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the closest I could come using a different approach from the OP and MasterID:

`asm("ret");`

The idea is to manipulate the stack as clumsily as possible.  I believe gcc will compile this.

Answer (score 0):

From a Unix (mostly Linux) perspective:

If we define "access violation" as "any signal" that fills in the `si_addr` field of `siginfo_t`, then according to `sigaction(2)` that is: `SIGILL, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, and SIGTRAP`.

- `SIGILL` can be generated by executing any invalid instruction, including permanently invalid instructions such as `ud2` on x86 (encoded as `0x0F 0x0B`), but jumping to a random point often generates this anyway.
- `SIGFPE` can be generated by dividing any integer by `0` or dividing the most negative integer by `-1`
- `SIGSEGV` can be generated by a read or write to any unmapped or `PROT_NONE`'d page, or a write to a read-only page.
- `SIGBUS` I have never figured out where it comes from.
- `SIGTRAP` can be generated by your arch's breakpoint instruction, which on x86 is `int3`, which is the single byte `0xcc`. From one perspective, that is the shortest possible code. If you insist on the shorest possible *C* code you'd have to wrap it in an `asm` block according to your compiler's whims.

There are also other examples involving syscalls such as `kill`.

Comment: raise(SIGSEGV); seems closest, still the code is not shorter.